# How to convert IN condition to INNER JOIN condition - join is slower

Tags: mysql, performance, join, sugarcrm

I have a query which is very slow in INNER JOIN condition, but is faster when used in WHERE IN clause:

**Slower Inner join:**

```sql
SELECT  * 
FROM cases
left join
(
    select tst.team_set_id 
    from team_sets_teams tst 
    INNER JOIN team_memberships team_memberships 
    ON tst.team_id = team_memberships.team_id
       AND team_memberships.user_id = '1'
       AND team_memberships.deleted=0 group by tst.team_set_id
) cases_tf 
ON cases_tf.team_set_id = cases.team_set_id
LEFT JOIN contacts_cases 
ON contacts_cases.case_id = cases.id 
   AND contacts_cases.deleted = 0
where cases.deleted=0 
ORDER BY cases.name LIMIT 0,20;
```

**Faster where in:**

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM cases 
LEFT JOIN contacts_cases 
ON contacts_cases.case_id = cases.id 
   AND contacts_cases.deleted = 0
where cases.deleted=0 
  and cases.team_set_id in  (
            select tst.team_set_id 
            from team_sets_teams tst
            INNER JOIN team_memberships team_memberships 
            ON tst.team_id = team_memberships.team_id
               AND team_memberships.user_id = '1'
               AND team_memberships.deleted=0 
           group by tst.team_set_id
)
ORDER BY cases.name LIMIT 0,20;
```

---

The explain plan for INNER JOIN and WHERE IN clause are below:

**Inner Join:**

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys                              | key                 | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>       | ALL  | NULL                                       | NULL                | NULL    | NULL                              |      4 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | cases            | ref  | idx_cases_tmst_id                          | idx_cases_tmst_id   | 109     | cases_tf.team_set_id              | 446976 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | contacts_cases   | ref  | idx_con_case_case                          | idx_con_case_case   | 111     | sugarcrm.cases.id                 |      1 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | team_memberships | ref  | idx_team_membership,idx_teammemb_team_user | idx_team_membership | 109     |                                   |      2 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tst              | ref  | idx_ud_team_id                             | idx_ud_team_id      | 109     | sugarcrm.team_memberships.team_id |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**While in condition:**

```
------+-----------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table            | type  | possible_keys                              | key                 | key_len | ref                               | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | cases            | index | NULL                                       | idx_case_name       | 768     | NULL                              |   20 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | contacts_cases   | ref   | idx_con_case_case                          | idx_con_case_case   | 111     | sugarcrm.cases.id                 |    1 |                                              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | team_memberships | ref   | idx_team_membership,idx_teammemb_team_user | idx_team_membership | 109     | const                             |    2 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tst              | ref   | idx_ud_team_id                             | idx_ud_team_id      | 109     | sugarcrm.team_memberships.team_id |    1 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Though there are indexes, I couldn't figure out what the problem. Please help me out. Thanks.
(This is a query in sugarcrm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to convert `IN` condition to `INNER JOIN`.
A query with `IN` condition is called **semi-join**.
A semi-join returns rows from one table that would join with another table, but without performing a complete join.
Here is a simple example of a semi-join query using IN operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE some-column IN (
   SELECT some-other-column
   FROM table2
   WHERE some-conditions
)
```

the above semi-join can be converted to semantically equivalent query
(eqivalent - means `giving exactly same results`)
using EXISTS operator and dependend subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 1
   FROM table2
   WHERE some-conditions
     AND table1.some-column = table2.some-other-column
)
```

Most leading databases use the same plan for both of the above queries, and their speed is the same,
unfortunately this is not always true for MySql.

Joins and semi joins are totally different queries, with completely different execution plans,
 so comparing their speed is like comparing apples to onions.
You can try to convert the first query with IN into a query with EXIST, but not into the join.

Comment: Thanks, but we ended up removing the Team condition altogether.